# Does the assigned Vault Number have significance beyond identification?

Tags: fallout-shelter

In Fallout Shelter, the first thing you can do is pick the three-digit number of your vault.  This seems significant, but I suspect it is not.

Other than labeling your vault and helping you distinguish between playing multiple vaults simultaneously on the same device, is this number significant?  Does it set a standard randomization seed or starting layout, or are there specific easter eggs with a given vault number?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Primarily, the vault number is just a means to identify a specific vault, so that players can easily identify a given vault between other options.

If you consider Fallout Shelter canon, each vault number coincides with an [actual vault](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Vault), in the Fallout universe. In the canon, each vault played host to a specific experiment. Experiments varied, from having a vault with deliberately-dim lights, to having a vault that contaminated its residents with excess radiation, to having a vault comprised entirely of children.

Players wishing to engage in a deeper level of immersion may wish to select a number associated with a known vault, and recreate the experiment. However, there is no game play mechanic that makes obvious game changes based off the designated vault number, and not all experiments can be recreated with the available game mechanics.

Answer (score -2):

I think it holds significantly a number of things such as what kind of dwellers you get and how many come to you because I picked 22 and I got intelligent dwellers and stuff like that so I googled vault 22 and it was a very intelligent vault that was full of intelligent dwellers so I picked a different number and I got another set of dwellers that was different but still resembled what I found on google

Answer (score -5):

My first vault was 117, it started good but became a hellhole with resources. I do 1 and 0 now, they never fail... 1 is better, usually. 3 power armor, one at game start in vault 1.